# Lua string patterns

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching, string-parsing

I'm trying to parse a string but I'm new to pattern matching. 
Here's my code:

```
str = "One[0:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0:1][0:1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0:0.5]/Two[0:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0:1.5]/"

for i in string.gmatch(str, "[%a%s]*[%[%]%d:,]*/") do
print("sequence: "..i)
end
```

It should print
One[0:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0:1][0:1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0:0.5]
Two[0:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0:1.5]

but instead it prints

sequence: 5]/
sequence: 5]/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `.` in your pattern: `"[%a%s]*[%[%]%d:%.,]*/"`, so `0.5` or `1.5` can't match. It just matches the last digit.

Comment: Dang, so close. Thank you.